# Network Dataset — can't solve route

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I read this topic and I have same problem as others. When I use network analyst on one line, the module works successfully. But for multilines, this warning comes:

```
No route from location "Graphic Pick 1" to location "Graphic Pick 2".
```

What can I do? Could you explain more, please ?

Comment: Hey Saka -
Connectivity is a primary concern when using the Network Dataset for route tracing, or for any network analysis in general. Even when your lines appear connected at a zoomed-out view, they may not actually be connected (co-located in terms of endpoints or vertices). Maybe review the datasets you've used to build your network in terms of their connectivity? Maybe also check any options you've specified for cluster tolerance where building the network - Best Luck:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Understanding_connectivity/004700000009000000/

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118944/) and see if it helps.