# Connectivity Issue in Road Network - Error Graphic Pick 1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, openstreetmap, network-analyst

I have read around 6 various forums posts and still could not figure out where I was making the mistake so please help me.

I have downloaded the OSM shapefile and and have clipped a pretty large area which I need for some analysis I need to make.

I have attached the shapefile I was working on. Exact Coordinates I am having problem are: 55.733952 24.180805 Decimal Degrees

Referring to Attached Picture Route is unable to resolve for Point 4 to 5, while up to 4 it works fine.

[image]

The shapefile is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eni5pzarz47r19d/AADs18NIXM32BH3p5IixqC1Ba?dl=0).

Comment: Check the direction of travel for each of those edges and the connectivity.

Comment: please advice, on how to check that ?

Comment: Before building any network datasets, consider going this excellent tutorial to understand the basics - http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32890

Comment: Impossible to say from just the provided information. It would be helpful to see your edge and node layers in the network screenshot. Furthering Alex's suggestion with more detail on looking at connectivity, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112978/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118944/ Marco_B's answer could also help avoid the issues in the first place, but as both he and Alex point out there's some cleanup involved in preparing data to use as a network.

Comment: thank you chris alex and marco. Let me look into all these four possible solutions and i'll get back to post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot, you are most likely using ArcGIS. In that case, I strongly recommend you to not use any shapefiles as the source of your routing network, but use ESRI's free "ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap", which is a very useful ModelBuilder toolbox with tools for OpenStreetMap data.

It has build-in tools for downloading the required data, and fixes common geometric errors in OSM data. It also includes configuration files for building a routing network of OSM data.

This workflow will likely be more reliable than downloading shapefiles and trying to re-invent the wheel...

You can find the toolbox here (10.2.x):
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=16970017f81349548d0a9eead0ebba39
or here (10.3.x):
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=75716d933f1c40a784243198e0dc11a1